# Delete a salesforce record using Azure DataFactory

Tags: salesforce, azure-data-factory

I have a use case where I need to insert/update & delete data  in SF via ADF. The salesforce connector that's native to ADF lets you insert or upsert but I don't see a delete option. I am curious if there is a native way of doing this  from data factories ?

Comment: Data Factory doesn't support allow delete option for now.  It means there isn't a way to do it from Data Factory.

Comment: Hello @Bond, do you have any other concerns?